# Multiple entity JOIN in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot so I was wondering how do I join and return a dataset from multiple entities using native query. Like

```
Select p.a, q.b, r,c from table1 p, table2 q, table3 r where p.id = q.id and q.flag = r.flag;
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom object in JPQL to pass these values or use object array.

Create a class with constructor taking these arguments.

Example:

```
@Query(value = "Select new com.path.to.class.Aggregate(p.a, q.b, r.c) 
       from table1 p, table2 q, table3 r where p.id = q.id and q.flag = r.flag")
```

Or use `List<Object[]>` as return type. The first element in list will contain these 3 objects.

Comment: @Embeddable worked for me, although the underlying idea was yours. Thanks a bunch